# How do I detect the sharp edges in the following image?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, python, opencv

[image]

I am looking to count the sharp pointy triangular things in the image. However I was unable to do so. One approach I did try was take a convex hull of the contour and then find convex defects but it led to lot of irregularities. You can find the it in the labelled image below. [image]

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  Can you explain a bit more about how you labelled the red points? And then why some of them are "irregularities" ?

Comment: @PeterK. After I got the contour of my desired region (represented in green dots), I tried taking a convex hull of the contour which are represented by blue dots, Using my convex hull and contour I passed it to opencv's find convex defect and the result I got are the red points in the image. I was expecting convex defect to be found only on the sharp 8 regions but I got it on the entire outline.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I solved this problem using a simple solution. After I computed my convex defects in my countours, I performed a point polygon test and found the distance between the point in the convex defect and the hull. And I gave a threshold after looking at the distance of the points and all the sharp points were in the threshold greater than approximately 30. So this filtered my points